# What does __declspec(uuid(" ComObjectGUID ")) expand to?

Tags: c++, declspec

I have a piece of code that uses [Microsoft-specific extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the C++:

```
interface __declspec(uuid("F614FB00-6702-11d4-B0B7-0050BABFC904"))
ICalculator : public IUnknown
{ 
    //...
};
```

What does this sentence expand to? How can I rewrite it with ANSI C++?

Comment: @Mat: More like, it's a `#define` for `struct`.

Comment: @Mat: Well, that's `__interface` (note the underscores), there's also a `#define interface struct` in the IUnknown header.

Comment: @Xeo, I fill like @Mat just has retired:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a macro so it doesn't "expand" to anything. It merely decorates the type with a given UUID in the object file metadata, which can then be extracted later with the [__uuidof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61.aspx) operator.

Comment: Thanks! Will static member + static method like `get_uuid()` simulate the same thing?

Comment: @ezpresso : It could, yes, if you have the ability to change the definition of every class in question (unlike `__declspec(uuid)` which can be used non-intrusively).

Answer (score 5):

You can also use templates (traits), if you need to statically "attach" a guid to the interface. Consider:

In a common h-file you create an empty unspecialized template:

```
template<typename TInterface> struct TInterfaceTraits {}
```

When defining your interface, write a template specialization for it (or you can write it in any other place including just before usage):

```
class ICalculator : public IUnknown
{ 
    //...
};
template<> struct TInterfaceTraits<class ICalculator > { 
    static GUID guid() { 
        return IID_ICalculator ; 
    } 
};
```

Then to get it's uuid you can write something like:

```
ICalculator *pCalcFace;
pObject->QueryInterface(TInterfaceTraits<ICalculator>::guid(), (void**)pCalcFace);
```

Of cause you can write (I leave it to you) a template wrapper to QueryInterface, which will use the traits to automatically supply proper guid, and that will be even easier to use, i.e.

```
ICalculator *pCalcFace = QueryInterface<ICalculator>(pObject);
```